# SSIS sending query with data parameter to Oracle cloud VS-2019 and MS Oracle Source

Tags: oracle, ssis, ssis-2019

Already checked this post: [SSIS and sending query with date to Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732117/ssis-and-sending-query-with-date-to-oracle)

And I'm using variable query per below thread
[SSIS - Using parameters in Oracle Query using Attunity Oracle Datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774545/ssis-using-parameters-in-oracle-query-using-attunity-oracle-datasource)

Tool used: VS-2019 
Data flow: MS Oracle Source (for VS-2019)
My source is Snowflake cloud. I'm successfully able to get the max date from table and store in Object type variable (named:- @var_Snowflake_Table_maxDate). Then I use a script task to convert the value to string type.
Code for script task is:

```
 public void Main()
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter A = new OleDbDataAdapter(); //using System.Data.OleDb; ADDED above in NAMESPACES
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

            A.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::var_Snowflake_Table_maxDate"].Value);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                object[] array = row.ItemArray;
                Dts.Variables["User::var_CreateDate"].Value = array[0].ToString();
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

This sets my param of @var_CreateDate String type correctly. I tried this on local machine and was able to pass the value to a native instance of sql-server(yes NOT oracle). Just to test my parameters from script task works.
Finally: I'm using VS-2019's MS Oracle Source to pass the value into Oracle cloud server. Sample query's I have tried

```
"select * from Table where rownum <= 5 and NVL(CREATE_DATE,UPDATE_DATE) = " +"'05-09-2020'"
```

::::evals to::::
    select * from relate.awd_acct_activity where rownum <= 5 and NVL(CREATE_DATE,UPDATE_DATE) = '2020-05-09'
and this works. But value is hard coded.
Try 2:

```
"select * from table  where rownum <= 50 and 
NVL(CREATE_DATE,UPDATE_DATE) = " +"'@[User::var_CreateDate]'"
```

Try 3:

```
"select * from table  where rownum <= 50 and 
NVL(CREATE_DATE,UPDATE_DATE) = to_date(" +"'@[User::var_CreateDate]'"+")"
```

Try 4:

```
"select * from table where rownum <= 50 and 
NVL(CREATE_DATE,UPDATE_DATE) = to_date(" +"'@[User::var_CreateDate]'"+",'YYYY-MM-DD')"
```

None of try 2 through 4 eval correctly. Can I have some guidance into how to pass this parameter to Oracle cloud.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to figure out the syntax for a variable, that would hold the query text. You can try something like this:

```
"select * from table where rownum <= 50 and 
NVL(CREATE_DATE,UPDATE_DATE) = to_date(" + "'" + @[User::var_CreateDate] + "'" + ",'YYYY-MM-DD')"
```

Comment: Believe it or NOT what worked was another co-worker shared. In script task I had to put additional " ' " (single quotes) to encapsulate the date. And then within SSIS I had to created a 3rd variable to type string and assign the value of variable 2 (the one from script task with single quotes). Assign this 3rd variable to query. AND that worked.